# How to link to parent site (ie index.html) from a page that has been loaded into a div using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This must be a quite common thing to do but I can't find any answers.

Our parent  document is called index.html. 
In this document we have a button, and two divs.

One called #pitch, one called #header.

When button is pressed jQuery loads contact.html into #pitch.
Something like this:

```
$(button).click(function() {
   $("#pitch").load("contact.html");
});
```

So far everything good. But now, how do I create a link inside contact.html (which now is the child) to #header which is inside the parent document?

ie:

```
$(SomeThingInContact.Html).click(function() {
   $("#header").text("new text");

});
</script>
```

UPDATE:

According to the answers yet maybe my questions has been unclear.

The problem is that the contact.html that is loaded into the div #pitch
doesn't know about it's parent document index.html. 
But I want to make changes FROM contact.html TO #header which is in index.html

I've tried top.getElementById("header").
Also tried window.document.parent.getElementById.

Of what I understand these only work with iFrames, or?

Thanx

Comment: Have you tried this and seen that it doesn't work? Because it certainly looks like it should work.

Comment: Yepp I have tried. Please read my UPDATE above. I'm trying to link to a div in another page. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try to find this guy before you use .text

```
$("#header").text("new text");

$("#header").find("#elementtofind").text("new text");
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't help since #header is placed in another document. Please read my Update above, been trying to clarify my prob.